# Task with nested subqueries in SQL

Tags: sql

Using tables HR.DEPARTMENTS and HR.EMPLOYEES, create a list of departments that have employees named John.

Here is an example of the employees and departments table:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   EMAIL   PHONE_NUMBER    HIRE_DATE   JOB_ID  SALARY COMMISSION_PCT   MANAGER_ID  DEPARTMENT_ID
   100   Steven           King     SKING    515.123.4567    17-JUN-03   AD_PRES   24000      -         -             90

DEPARTMENT_ID   DEPARTMENT_NAME MANAGER_ID  LOCATION_ID
10               Administration     200         1700
```

i tried like this:

```
select department_id from HR.EMPLOYEES, HR.DEPARTMENTS 
where 'John' = (select first_name from hr.employees)
```

How can I rewrite the query so that it works correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use an `IN` clause here:

```
SELECT department_id, department_name
FROM hr.departments
WHERE department_id IN (
    SELECT department_id
    FROM hr.employees
    WHERE first_name = 'John');
```

A `JOIN` is of course possible here, but should not be necessary because we don't want to apply further conditions here or fetch other data from the employees table.

It's enough to know John works in this department.

A side note: Your task to "create a list of departments" is very likely not correctly done by selecting the id only. So I selected also the department_name in the query above. And I assume it would be even better and correct to select the name only instead of the id and name.

Answer (score 1):

I would use exists logic here rather than a join:

```sql
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID
FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS d
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM HR.EMPLOYEES e
    WHERE e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID AND
          e.FIRST_NAME = 'John'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select department_id from HR.EMPLOYEES WHERE first_name = 'Steven';
```

This should work. You don't need a JOIN.

If you want to ensure that the department_id exists in the DEPARTMENTS table, you can add a foreign key constraint on the `DEPARTMENT_ID` column of the table `EMPLOYEES`.

Comment: It's very unlikely that the requirement to "create a list of departments" is satisfied by simply listing the department id's. An id is usually something which means nothing for a user and often shouldn't even be shown, but is just used to cover relations between tables. This means it's probably required here to select the department_name from the departments table. But yes, otherwise, this will be sufficient ;)

Comment: @JonasMetzler Yes, you are right, I didn't notice that the requirement of  "create a list of departments", so the accepted answer is right.