# Task on nested subqueries in sql

Tags: sql

Using the HR.LOCATIONS, HR.DEPARTMENTS and HR.EMPLOYEES tables, display full data on the location of the employee's workplace with ID 105.

I tried to implement it like this, but it doesn't work:

```
select street_address from hr.locations
where street_address in (select location_id from hr.departments
                            where(select department_id from hr.employees 
                                where employee_id = "105"))
```

Here's what the tables look like:
hr.employees:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   EMAIL   PHONE_NUMBER    HIRE_DATE   JOB_ID  SALARY COMMISSION_PCT   MANAGER_ID  DEPARTMENT_ID
   100   Steven           King     SKING    515.123.4567    17-JUN-03   AD_PRES   24000      -         -             90
```

hr.departments:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID   DEPARTMENT_NAME MANAGER_ID  LOCATION_ID
10              Administration  200           1700
```

hr.locations:

```
LOCATION_ID STREET_ADDRESS        POSTAL_CODE   CITY    STATE_PROVINCE  COUNTRY_ID
 1000       1297 Via Cola di Rie    00989       Roma          -              IT
```

Comment: You should respond to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74684191/task-with-nested-subqueries-in-sql) before posting a new one.

Comment: Chose the correct answers in the previous questions

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select street_address from hr.locations where street_address in (select location_id from hr.departments where employee_id = "105")
```

where(...), I don't understand what are you doing

Comment: select street_address from hr.locations where street_address in (select location_id from hr.departments where(select department_id from hr.employees where employee_id = "105) .
You apparently did not finish the last part, I tried to finish it like this, it still didn’t work out

Comment: select street_address from hr.locations
where  location_id in (select location_id from hr.departments
                            where  department_id in (select department_id from hr.employees 
                                where employee_id = "105"))

Comment: why not use inner join?